# Split string into several ints for 2D array

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array

So I have a text file that reads something like:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5

2, 3, 4, 5, 6

3, 4, 5, 6, 7

4, 5, 6, 7, 8

...
```

I want to read this file into a 2D array in python such that `matrix[]` array will hold arrays containing integers of each line.

For example, `matrix[2][3] == 6`

I am not sure if my logic or programming is right in this (I am new to python) but here is what I have so far:

```
matrix = []

i = 0
with open('matrix.txt', 'r') as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        matrix.append([])
        matrix[i] = int(n) for n in line.split(',')
        i += 1

openfile.close()

print (matrix)
#print (matrix[2][3])
```

I get an invalid syntax error covering the nested `for` statement, as in `int (n) for n`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) must be enclosed in square brackets `[...]`:

```
matrix[i] = [int(n) for n in line.split(',')]
#           ^                               ^
```

Also, there is no reason to do `openfile.close()` because the with-statement automatically closes the file for you when control leaves its code block (that is what it is for).